# Data Modal not firing on Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this input button:

```
<input type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NotAvailable" id="StandardProductAddToCart" name="Add to Cart" value="ADD TO CART" alt="Add to Cart" style="cursor:not-allowed;" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Where I'd like to fire my modal on if clicked.

My modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="NotAvailable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NotAvailableLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <img class="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/x_white.png" height="20" width="20" alt="X" />
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Not Available</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Not available for online orders. Please call 1-800-543-8995 to order; thank you.</strong></div>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the HTML, the Modal comes after the Input as well. Should it come before the Input?

Comment: These snippets (minus the `disabled` attribute on the `input`) works with the latest version of Bootstrap - please check this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lomas/1/). Could you please edit that bin to try and reproduce the error at your end?

Comment: @FloydPink So..Is the issue the disabled attribute? I'm not sure. That's where I'm having the issue. I need the button to be disabled / unclickable, but if the user does click it, I want there to be some text explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the URL you provided, this will let you keep the disabled="disabled" attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#StandardProductAddToCart:disabled').click(function()
        {
            $('#NotAvailable').modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to have worked. Just tried it on my test environment I linked.

Comment: The script is not appearing in the URL you linked to.

Comment: It is in http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/Javascript/Product.js

Which is called in the header of the Product page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the modal comes before or after the button.

Your button is disabled so if you remove disabled="disabled", does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does. But, I need the button to be disabled / unclickable, but if the user does click it, I want there to be some text explaining why it's disabled, which is what the modal does.

Comment: Ah, now we're at the crux of the issue. :) Then I'd suggest styling the button to look like it's disabled with CSS but not actually be disabled, or perhaps you can use jQuery to add a click event to the button that fires the modal using $('#NotAvailable').modal();

Comment: I've attempted that here:
http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/product.aspx?p=SHR210

But for some reason, it won't fire in Firefox or Safari when I click "Add to Cart".

Comment: Posted a new answer now you've explained the situation. I edited your page in Chrome to test it out and it fires the modal with the button disabled.

Comment: That doesn't appear to have worked. Just tried it on my test environment I linked. I placed the JS into Product.js